# itemlistener gets event after focus is removed from jcombobox

Tags: java, events, swing, jcombobox

This must be a misunderstanding from my side, but I have the following:
I have added an ItemListener to a Jcombobox.
In the item listener, I check in the event if it is of type ItemSelected.
If it is, I update a value in a JTextPane.
The problem is that it works as follows:
I click on a new value in the jcombobox and nothing is changed in the jtextfield. I have to actually click on another component e.g. the jtextfield and then the jtextfield is updated.
It seems that the focus must be removed from the jcombobox so that the event change is dispatched to the itemlistener code.
Is this how it is supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to handle the event without needing to remove focus?

**UPDATE:** This my code and the method updateJTextPane is called **after I click on another component** an not when I select a new value from the combo. I.e. combo has value "1", I click on the drop-down list and click on "2". Current selected item is now "2". My method is not being called at this point. I click on a second combo box, second combo has focus and then my method updateJTextPane() is called. Why?
**UPDATE 2:**

```
//Code from Netbeans generator
JComboBox myCbx = new javax.swing.JComboBox();    
myCbx.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
myCbx.setName("myCbx"); // NOI18N 
//My ItemListener
class myItemListener implements ItemListener{
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
            if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) { // Item was just selected
                updateJTextPane();
            }    
         }
    }
//add item listener to combo
myCbx.addItemListener(new myItemListener());
```

**UPDATE 3:**Inner class myItemListener is added to 5 more comboboxes in the same JDialog if this matters in a way I do not know
Thank you

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: @user384706: Can you try the two tests I mention in my answer?

Comment: @Grodriguez:Thank you for your help.The tests also failed, but when I restarted my PC, there was no problem, with my code and with your tests. Not sure how it stuck. I will close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how it is supposed to work. Item events should be generated immediately whenever the selected item changes.

I suggest to start with a simple example such as [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JComboBoxaddItemListenerItemListenerlis.htm) and see if events are actually being generated. If this works, then you only need to search for the differences between this and your own code.

**Update:**

Your `itemStateChanged` method looks fine, the problem must be elsewhere. Perhaps there is something wrong with `updateJTextPane`. What happens if you replace the call to `updateJTextPane` with a `System.out.println`? Also, can you print out the source of the event (`ie.getSource()`) and verify that the event is actually coming from the first combo box?

If you post a self-contained example that can be compiled and run, it should be much easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @Godriguez: The difference is that in my itemlistener i check: if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) { //call my function}. You are saying I should remove this check? But then how would I know that the item selected was changed?

Comment: No, what I said is that you should try with a simple example first, then incrementally add functionality to see where is the problem. Does the example I linked work for you?

Comment: @user384706, this process is know as creating a SSCCE (http://sscce.org). Every question should have a SSCCE included. There is no way anybody can tell what you are doing wrong based on the 4 lines of code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to handle the event without needing to remove focus?
>   Sure it is! :)

Here's a sample of how it could work, assuming my understanding of your requirements is correct:

```
class ComboListener implements ItemListener {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            System.out.println("Selected Item: \""
                + ((JComboBox)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem() + "\"");
        }
    } 
}
```

If you don't add the if check, you are going to perform the action for both the first item being unselected and the second one being selected.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I have the if condition in the itemStateChanged method, and I get the event only after the focus is removed from the jcombobox.

Comment: @Cratylus the listener would be called once for the selection of the item you click and once for the unselection of the previously selected item. The if check helps reach to only the event for the item being selected, not for the unselection.

Comment: @trashgod thanks! :) It was my first post on Stack Overflow and hence the rather newbieness :)

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you described it, the following runs just fine:

```
class Frame extends JFrame {
    JComboBox  box;
    JTextField field;
    String[]   entries = { "one", "two", "three" };

    Frame() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        box = new JComboBox(entries);
        box.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    field.setText((String) box.getSelectedItem());
                }
            }
        });
        add(box);

        field = new JTextField();
        field.setColumns(10);
        add(field);

        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Frame frame = new Frame();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: @fcocq:strange. Could it be something to do with netbeans?I use IDE for my code

Comment: Could be, not sure how Netbeans generates GUI code. If your ItemListener is implemented by the enclosing class, e.g. "class Frame extends JFrame implements ItemListener" and added to other components as well then you also need to check for the component you're handling, e.g. if ((ie.getSource() == yourComboBox) && (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)) {...

Comment: @ fbcocq:The item listener is added to 5 more comboboxes. Does this matter somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the similar situation on Choice.
To me it more likes a bug in Java. My case is I have two Choices A and B. B depends on A's selection. For example, A={a1, a2, a3}. If A=a1 B is a Choice list of {1, 2, 3}. If A=a2, B is a list of {4,5,6}., If A= a3, B is a list of {7,8,9}. The flow is select a1 and then select 2 on B. Select a2 and B is in default index 0 (4) and select 5 on B, the itemStateChanged() funcation will not be called. It looks like the view control does not sync with the data set to it. The reason the itemStateChanged() is not called since the 5 has the same index of previous selection.